# Adding data to DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I have datagridview and I want to insert in it values that come from textbox a and a NumericUpDown box but I face a problem which is that these values inserted into the datagridview are not in the column that I specified.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(MaterialTextBox.Text);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(HoursNumericUpDown.Value);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(MarkNumericUpDown.Value);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(MarkPoints);
```

and by the way is that way of calculating the values that I get from NumericUpDown box is?

```
        decimal MarkPoints, x, y;
        x = HoursNumericUpDown.Value;
        y = MarkNumericUpDown.Value;
        MarkPoints = x * y;
```

Because when I write it with this way I got an error

> > decimal MarkPoints = HoursNumericUpDown.Value * HoursNumericUpDown.Value;

I think there is no different answer for example let's

```
HoursNumericUpDown value is 2 
MarkNumericUpDown value is 3
```

the answer in the first way is 6 which is correct but the answer in the second way is 4. 
what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

you must specify the cells of your row and then add the row to the dataGridView :

```
    Dim dgvRow As New DataGridViewRow
    Dim dgvCell As DataGridViewCell

    dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    dgvCell.Value = MaterialTextBox.Text
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

    dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    dgvCell.Value = HoursNumericUpDown.Value
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

    dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    dgvCell.Value = MarkNumericUpDown.Value
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

    dgvCell = New DataGridViewTextBoxCell()
    dgvCell.Value = MarkPoints
    dgvRow.Cells.Add(dgvCell)

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow)
```